# Cannot remove the HomeSync Icon

Tags: macos

I hooked my MacBook up to an Apple server for testing and I created a mobile account on the unit. I've since decided to go back to just having a local account on the MacBook. The process I did was to the following:

1. Create a new Admin account on the MacBook.
2. Log into the Admin account.
3. Backup the home folder of the network account.
4. Delete the network account from System Preferences -> Users.
5. Create a new local account with the same name as the old network account.
6. Restore the backed up home folder.
7. Reset all permissions on the restored home folder (`sudo chown …`).
8. Logged into the newly created local account.

Now everything has been working fine on my system and I'm not having any permissions issues, or weird ghosts coming out of the closet **except for one thing**.

I cannot seem to be able to get rid of the HomeSync icon from my toolbar. I've pressed <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> while dragging the icon off of the toolbar (disappears in a cloud of smoke), but when I log out and log back in, it's back.

How can I get rid of the HomeSync icon once and for all? I am trying this in [lion](/questions/tagged/lion)

---

#### update

Updating to [mountain-lion](/questions/tagged/mountain-lion) did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have been a bug in the OS that was finally fixed. I just "ignored it" for, well, months... and upon looking at this question today, I decided to look up, and low-and-behold, it's gone.

After months of having to drag it off of the bar, it's now gone for good. Not sure when it left, but it's fixed.